# Neighbour, town, dam, link relationships

Tags: list, prolog

In a prolog program as stated below:

```
town(a).
town(b).
town(c).
town(d).
dam(e).
dam(f).
link(a,b).
link(a,c).
link(c,d).
link(b,d).
link(b,c).
link(c,e).
link(a,e).
link(d,f).
neighbour(X,Y):- link(X,Y) ; link(Y,X).
```

Would this be the correct procedure **all_neighbours(L,X)** which returns a list L of all neighbouring towns to X: **all_neighbours(L,X):- town(Y), findall(Y, neighbour(X,Y), L).**

Would this be the correct procedure **has_dam(L)** which returns a list L of all towns that have at least one neighbouring dam: **has_dam(L):- dam(Y), town(X), findall(X, neighbour(X,Y), L).**

Would this be the correct procedure **no_dam(L)** which returns a list L of all towns that have no neighbouring dam: **no_dam(L):- town(X), not dam(Y), findall(X, neighbour(X,Y), L).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, none of these are correct. In the first, the call to `town` should be done within the scope of the `findall`:

```
all_neighbours(Neighbourhood, X) :-
    findall(Y, (town(Y), neighbour(X, Y)), Neighbourhood).
```

and similarly for the rest. Note the parentheses around the second argument to `findall`. These are required, since

```
findall(Y, town(Y), neighbour(X, Y), Neighbourhood)
```

would be parsed as a call to (the probably non-existant) `findall/4`.

To understand the `findall` query, spell it out:

> Find all `Y` such that (`Y` is a town and `X` neighbours `Y`) and call the result `Neighbourhood`.